# Как спарсить href с помощью библиотеки BeautifulSoup

Tags: python

```
<a href="tel:0872688490" class="button telephone"><span class="icon-phone-blue icon-phone-green"></span><span class="icon-phone-white"></span><span id="phone-number" class="label" data-shortname-text="Call" data-show-number-text="***Show phone number" _msthash="2043509" _msttexthash="79612">0872688490</span></a>
```

В данном случае, мне нужно получить значение href="tel:0872688490"

Будет супер, если вы сохраните это значение в переменную buotes. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

Url = 'url'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.01) AppleWebKit/531.3.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.1 Safari/531.3.3'}

response = requests.get(Url, headers=HEADERS)
soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')

elems = soup.findAll('a', class_='button telephone')
numbers = []
for i in elems:
    numbers.append(int(i.attrs["href"][4:]))
```

Вот полностью готовый парсер. Только надо URL подставить. В массив numbers выведут чистые номера.

Comment: Не могу найти слов, чтобы выразить благодарность. Спасибо!!!

Comment: Если вам не трудно, можете подсказать как спарсить номера из объявлений вот тут: https://www.gumtree.ie/s-stuff-for-sale/wicklow/v1c4l3300011p1

Comment: @Zar На этом сайте что бы спарсить номер нужен селениум. Его я не знаю, поэтому не могу вам помочь.